# Adding image layers to a pdf using iText 5 or 7

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext, layer

I need to create a pdf document with images that should be contained in layers. Each image should be contained in a layer, so that we can choose to make each image either visible or not.

I know that iText offers a class ***PdfLayer*** for that purpose but they don't explain how to use it. Surprisingly tutorials in the web don't cover this question.

This is a little start:

```
    // Creating a PdfWriter 
    String dest = "export.pdf"; 
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

    // Creating a PdfDocument  
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);


    // Adding an empty page 
    //pdfDoc.addNewPage(); 

    // Creating a Document   
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc); 

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Creating an ImageData object 
    String imageFile = "map.png"; 
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imageFile);

    // Creating an Image object 
    Image img = new Image(data);

    PdfLayer pdflayer = new PdfLayer("main layer", pdfDoc);
    pdflayer.setOn(true); 

    /* normally, here where the image should be added to the layer */
```

Hope for your help, thanks!

Comment: First of all, what exactly do you mean by layer? I ask because that is not a term defined in the pdf specification, so it might or might not mean the same for us. Do you e.g. mean optional content groups?

Comment: According to iText specification: An optional content group is a dictionary representing a collection of graphics that can be made visible or invisible dynamically by users of viewer applications. In iText they are referenced as layers.

Comment: Does my answer resolve your question? Or or there still open issues?

Comment: @mkl It does actually, thank you. But the concept of implementing layers in itext is indeed strange to me and difficult to grasp (start and end layers ??). And the big problem is that the official documentation doesn't explain anything.
Do you have any idea how to structure an ensemble of images within a table and use layers at the same time? (choose to show and hide an image within a cell). Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"But the concept of implementing layers in itext is indeed strange to me and difficult to grasp"* - The cause is that already the term "layer" is misleading; the official name in the PDF specifications is "optional content group", and that describes the concept better: Any drawn element can belong to such an OCG (or even multiple of them!), no matter how early or how late in the content stream that element is drawn. And elements may be made optional by enclosing them between the marked-content operators **BDC** and **EMC** with a marked-content tag of *OC*. iText mirrors this with start & end

Comment: *"Do you have any idea how to structure an ensemble of images within a table and use layers at the same time?"* - Admittedly I have no idea yet. When I wrote that answer, I did not stumble over any obvious high-level API support for adding single elements to an OCG.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add an image to a layer by starting that layer in the `PdfCanvas` to draw on, adding the image, and ending the layer therein again.

Depending on whether you want to do the content layout work yourself, you can do the image adding part directly or via a `Canvas`.

For example:

```java
try (   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(...);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc)   ) {
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(IMAGE_DATA);
    Image img = new Image(data);

    PdfLayer pdflayer = new PdfLayer("main layer", pdfDoc);
    pdflayer.setOn(true); 

    // using a Canvas, to allow iText layout'ing the image
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
    try (   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, document.getPageEffectiveArea(pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize()))   ) {
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("This image is added using a Canvas:"));
        pdfCanvas.beginLayer(pdflayer);
        canvas.add(img);
        pdfCanvas.endLayer();
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("And this image is added immediately:"));
    }

    // or directly 
    pdfCanvas.beginLayer(pdflayer);
    pdfCanvas.addImage(data, 100, 100, false);
    pdfCanvas.endLayer();
}
```

*([AddImageToLayer](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/AddImageToLayer.java#L41) test `testAddLikeIan`)*

<sub>*According to your question title you look for a solution for either iText 5 or iText 7. The code above is for iText 7, I used the current development version 7.1.4-SNAPSHOT.*</sub>